# activateRSS Error while Deploying the Managed Package from one org to another using Workbench Salesforce

Tags: managed-package, salesforcedx, deployment, workbench

Using Workbench I retrieved the Installed package from the Org1 and then deployed it to another Org, but I am getting the error:

`Required field is missing: activateRSS`

Then I changed the version of the package.xml file from 48 to 42, now I am getting the error:

`Incorrect or missing password.`

Anyone please suggest me how to proceed please...

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a bug in Salesforce when retrieving the metadata. It sets the `activateRSS` element to an invalid value, which you need to manually update to be something that is valid.

My colleague wrote more about it on a blog post: https://gearset.com/blog/installed-packages-v43-and-activaterss